# Как задать несколько значений в одну переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне значения `Как дела` и `как дела` поместить в одну переменную?

Необходимо сравнить ее с другой переменной, если хоть один вариант совпадет, необходимо чтобы в `if` что-то произошло.

Comment: Для какой задачи? `x = ["Как дела", "как дела"]; print(x[0], x[1])` - называется «список»

Comment: мне необходимо сравнить его с другой переменной если хоть одни вариант совпадет необходимо что бы что-то произошло (в if)

Comment: `s = 'KaK дЕлА'` → `if 'как дела' in s.lower(): print('match')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте кортеж:

```
words = ("Как дела", "как дела")
```

А вообще коллекций разных в питоне много, какую лучше использовать зависит от сценария использования.

По дополнительному вопросу из комментария:

```
if "как дела" in words:
    print("Нашёл!")
```

Comment: ТЫ ПРОСТО БОГ python. 2 раз помогаешь  примного благодарен

Comment: @DimaBroLach Ну это азы питона, честно говоря, продолжайте изучать, там будет ещё сложнее и интереснее )

Answer (score 0):

`string = "как дела", "Как дела"`

для вывода или использования одного из значений:
`print(string[0])` - тут выводится "как дела"

Answer (score 0):

> мне необходимо сравнить его с другой переменной если хоть одни вариант совпадет необходимо что бы что-то произошло (в if)

Можно сделать так (если есть две переменных с несколькими значениями):

```py
a = ["Как дела", "как дела"]
b = ["Привет", "привет", "Как дела"]
for itema in a:
    for itemb in b:
        if itema == itemb: # if-блок, который ищет совпадения
            pass # Тут всё, что необходимо выполнить
```

Или так (если есть одна переменная с несколькими значениями и другая с одним занчением):

```
a = ["Как дела", "как дела"]
b = "Как дела"
if b in a: # if-блок, который ищет совпадения
    pass # Тут всё, что необходимо выполнить
```